# C#: How to plot a function using console

Tags: c#, function, plot, console-application

I want to plot any polynomial function in C# using the console application, without using any windows or forms, I searched a lot but all I found was in window application or involving MATLAB and what I want is something just in the console.

I want it to plot any polynomial function given, for example; the coefficients are stored in an array, and i want to plot the function related to it, for example:

The array is:

`double[] array = new double[4] { 2 , 0 , -4 , 3 };`

Then the function is: 3X^3 - 4X^2 + 2

And it will be plotted on the XY-Plane like this:

For Example: X + 1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD3tb.jpg

Any help is appreciated.

Update:

Using the method you provided, I tried this code:

```
        WriteAt("|", 40, 0);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 1);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 2);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 3);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 4);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 5);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 6);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 7);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 8);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 9);

        WriteAt("-----------------------------------------", 20, 10);

        WriteAt("|", 40, 11);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 12);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 13);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 14);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 15);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 16);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 17);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 18);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 19);
        WriteAt("|", 40, 20);

        WriteAt("*", 32, 12);
        WriteAt("*", 34, 11);
        WriteAt("*", 36, 10);
        WriteAt("*", 38, 9);
        WriteAt("*", 40, 8);
        WriteAt("*", 42, 7);
        WriteAt("*", 44, 6);
        WriteAt("*", 46, 5);
        WriteAt("*", 48, 4);
```

And I got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqLz2.jpg

So, now I have to give the WriteAt function the points that must be drawn but putting in mind that the origin is (40,10) in my plotting ??

I subtract 2 from the x-axis because the "-" is half the size of the "|" so the plot will be kinda scaled.

Comment: so you want to draw on the console ? in c# using only .Net classes ? no native or un-safe code ?

Comment: +1... Not sure why it was given -1... [ASCII-art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) is very old, almost ancient.

Comment: So what's your question?  Do you just want us to do it all for you?  Are you having some problem implementing this, if so, what?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Why +1 a question that doesn't even ask a question?  It does nothing other than list the high level requirements.

Comment: @Servy, not sure... probably in a way too good mood. Will go down appropriately as day goes on...

Comment: Is using for loop not allowed?

Comment: I know this has a lot of down votes, but this is very useful in the debug console for tools like Visual Studio and Netbeans.  These modern IDE's allow console debugging output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) and draw "*" as needed as if you have something like 80x25 display with pixels.

You will need to scale your `x` and `y` axis accordingly to fit into screen space. Don't forget that `y` on screen is down, when on normal drawings it is up - need to inverse in addition to shift when computing screen position (same as regular graphics).

Essentials of sample available in the above MSDN article:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorTop+x, Console.CursorLeft+y);
Console.Write("*");
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply, can you please have a look at the update in the question ?
Because it's too long to be posted here in a comment on your answer.

Comment: @AbdallahIs'haqat, You should be able to come up with conversion easily as soon as you write what you want down like:(2,3) -> (42,7), (-10, 1)->(30,9). Side note: read on loops (`for`)...